# Facebook query info when not logged in

Tags: facebook

Ok so i have gotten to the point where for my admins I can log them in, post to their fan pages, post comments and everything works well.

I have done this with the javascript api.

Now I am t the point where I want pull things like the feed from their fan page wall to display to site viewers. Obviously I dont want the average site viewer to have to log in to see the feed from the fan page. I just want to display it on my web page.

Is this possible to do with no authentication?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most definitely possible. Take a look at at [this](http://fbrell.com/xfbml/fb%3afan) example.